How can I have a UDP server in a docker container and a UDP client on the host?
server.py
import socket
from time import sleep

write_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    write_socket.sendto("Hello!".encode("utf-8"), ("127.0.0.1", 8001))
    sleep(0.1)

client.py
import socket

read_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
read_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8001))
data = read_socket.recv(128)

print(data.decode("utf-8"))

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8

COPY ./server.py .

If I just run server.py and client.py on the host, there's no problem. The client gets the string from the server and prints it. If I try to run the server in a container like this:
docker build . -t pyserver
docker run -it --rm -p 8001:8001/udp pyserver python ./server.py

and then run python3 client.py, I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 4, in <module>
    read_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8001))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use


This is a strange meaning of "client" and "server" you use. Commonly a "server" is providing a service (hence the name) and the client is accessing the service. This means the server is the one which binds to an address and receives data there from the client. And the client is the one initiating the communication to the address the server is bound to. Because of this kind of confusion of naming you also get the confusion with docker: the port mapping in docker is for the case when there is a real server in docker (bound to an address), not a client which you just wrongly call server.

@SteffenUllrich The actual "server" in my true use case is actually doing both, it has one port for receiving data and one for publishing data, both UDP. Maybe it's still not the best terminology. My guess is that when I publish a port, Docker binds to that port (I can see the connection with netstat when I run the container), which it shouldn't be in this case. But if I don't pass -p to Docker, my "client" can't get any data from my "server" at all.

There is no bound socket in your "server" running inside docker, so mapping this non-existing binding to outside the docker makes no sense. Instead you have this binding in your "client" running outside of docker, and it conflicts there with the mapping you asked docker to do, because you basically asked docker to bind to the same port outside of docker you already use outside of docker. I'm really not sure what you actually intend to do and your confusing use of terminology does not help.

But in short: mapping in docker makes sense if you have a bound socket INSIDE the container you want to make accessible from outside. If you instead want to access a  bound socket OUTSIDE the container from inside the container, then just do it - but the socket must be actually listen on an address reachable from inside docker (i.e. 127.0.0.1 does not work). Maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/92ltlj/docker_reverse_publishing_ports/ will help?

As noted in the comments, something sending data would normally be called the client, not the server, which is why the information I was finding on Google was leading me astray.
In fact, the only thing you need to change to make this work is pass --net host to docker run, and not -p.
